# Grails make the connection to hibernate change dynamically

Tags: grails

I’m trying to make the connection to hibernate change dynamically based on the application user logged in. 
I.E. Every application user will have his own oracle schema. To do so, I changed the values of **dataSourceUnproxied.username** and **dataSourceUnproxied.password** dynamically from the code depending on the logged on user, then I closed the connection and got the connection again with the new settings. It worked, but **the problem** is if two users are logged in to my application at the same time, the connection will be set to the connection of the last logged in user, and both users will use the same connection again. It seems that these variables are application scoped variables, which set the value for all the users.

Is there a way to make these values different based on the user session?

Comment: So essentially you want to use database authentication?

Comment: Look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/12009430/1264846

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your question is similar to this one 
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/unique-dataSource-per-HttpSession-td1343203.html

Basically you could come up with your own datasource implementation.

I believe that it may help you solve your issue with minor dark corners.